# Maven and jenkins 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have compiled maven manually in cmd and it is successfull. 
However, when i tried to run the jenkins job, it is saying

```
"'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
```

Jenkins console output:

```
enter code hereStarted by user prakash peram
```

Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\atmosphere3

> git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
>   Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>   git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/g0t4/jenkins2-course-spring-boot.git # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/g0t4/jenkins2-course-spring-boot.git
>   git.exe --version # timeout=10
>   git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/g0t4/jenkins2-course-spring-boot.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
>   git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
>   Checking out Revision 4bde91e33e2860b2aab142028c04eff37b7791f2 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
>   git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
>   git.exe checkout -f 4bde91e33e2860b2aab142028c04eff37b7791f2
>   Commit message: "Adding in jacoco code coverage"
>   git.exe rev-list --no-walk 4bde91e33e2860b2aab142028c04eff37b7791f2 # timeout=10
>   [atmosphere3] $ cmd.exe /C "mvn -f spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-atmosphere/pom.xml compile && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
>   'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
>   Finished: FAILURE

I have set the MVN_HOME and M2_HOME in the environment variables.

Please seek additional info if required.

Comment: Have you added %M2_HOME%\bin to PATH environment variable?

Comment: Where do I need to specify the path? in Jenkins?
I have added installation path in the maven installation.

Comment: Check section "4. Add To PATH" [here](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/).

Comment: For manual compile, it is working as expected and got the desired output. But I will need to do it in jenkins. That is throwing the error

Comment: Create and run bat file with following content:
    `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\atmosphere3"
    cmd.exe /C "mvn -f spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-atmosphere/pom.xml compile && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
    pause`

Let me know if it works. Also did you try my previous tip?

Comment: Yes, I have configured it correctly earlier and it is working for manual compilation. But jenkins does not recognize mvn. Let me try out your latest instruction

Answer (score 0):

you have to set up the global tool inside jenkins adding maven and JDK

Answer (score 0):

inside jenkins in the left side panel in dashboard we found general settings, then inside global tools we can configure the JDK and MAVEM environment in the same way as windows, but this time will be made it within localhost jenkins with the path of maven and jdk of program files

[image]

[image]